# Symfony: how to find out the list of the different urls to which the connected user can access

Tags: symfony, access-control

I want to compose an index page presenting to the logged in user the list of resource urls which he can access according to the roles assigned to him

I found a solution by parsing the security.yaml file using the Yaml component and going through the security.acces_control section:

```
security:
    ......
    access_control:
        - {path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
        - {path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER}
        - {path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - {path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - {path: ^/resetting, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - {path: ^/path1, roles: ROLE_USER}
        - {path: ^/path2, roles: ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR}
        - .....
        - {path: ^/pathn, roles: ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR}
```

Thus, if the logged in user only has the ROLE_USER role, he will only see /profile and /path1 on the index page.

But I know this way of doing that is bad practice.
Do you have a better solution with Symfony components to avoid parsing security.yaml?

I thought about using AccesMap but the 'security.acces_map' service is private and cannot be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on the **AccessMap** and **AccessDecisionManager** classes.

Since AccessMap is not autowired, it is necessary to write and declare a service allowing to wire it manually.

The declaration of this service in services.yaml:

```
App\Security\Util\AccessControlInterface:
    class: App\Security\Util\AccessControl
    arguments:
        - '@security.access_map'
```

The service code:

```
namespace App\Security\Util;

<? php declare (strict_types = 1);

interface AccessControlInterface {

    / **
    * Checks if the connected user can access to $path.
    *
    * @param string $path
    *
    * @return bool
    * /
    public function isPathAuthorized (string $path);

}
```

and

```
<? php declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Security\Util;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessMapInterface;

class AccessControl implements AccessControlInterface
{

    / **
    * @var array
    * /
    protected $server;

    / **
    * @var string
    * /
    protected $baseUrl;

    / **
    * @var\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessMapInterface
    * /
    protected $accessMap;

    / **
    * @var\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface
    * /
    protected $tokenStorage;

    / **
    * @var\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManagerInterface
    * /
    protected $accessDecisionManager;

    public function __construct (
        AccessMapInterface $accessMap,
        RequestStack $requestStack,
        TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage,
        AccessDecisionManagerInterface $accessDecisionManager
    )
    {
        $this->accessMap = $accessMap;
        $this->server = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->server->all();
        $this->baseUrl = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getBaseUrl();
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->accessDecisionManager = $accessDecisionManager;
    }

    public function isPathAuthorized (string $path)
    {
        $request = Request::create ($this->baseUrl. $path, 'GET', [], [], [], $this->server);
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
        [$attributes] = $this->accessMap->getPatterns ($request);
        if (null === $attributes) {
            $attributes = ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'];
        }
        return $this->accessDecisionManager->decide($token, $attributes, $request);
    }
}
```

Possible use from a controller:

```
use App\Security\Util\AccessControlInterface;
...

class IndexController extends AbstractController {

    public function index (Request $request, AccessControlInterface $accessControl)
    {
        if ($accessControl->isPathAuthorized("/path1")) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```